# Synchroteam Api integration in PHP Wordpress form

Tags: php, wordpress, api, web-services

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn6wC.png) in a Wordpress Site and I need to integrate it with Synchroteam Api and send its fields to Synchroteam. I asked my client for the APIs and he sent me this email.

Client: "We have open APIs available . Please visit https://api.synchroteam.com/

Also to access your account through the APIs they would need the authentication key.

Please go into configuration => More => (LHS Down) Authentication Key."

https://api.synchroteam.com/ I have checked this link here is so many APIs I don't know which to use. Please Help.
The form is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l8em.png).

Comment: which type of form you have.??

Comment: i have attached the image of the form you can see.

Answer (score 0):

As par your requirement you need to two API endpoint.

1. [customer](https://api.synchroteam.com/#send-customer) endpoint. Using this endpoint you can save all filed except **Upload Printer status page**  and **Upload sample page**.in this endpoint response you get customer id.
2. [attachments](https://api.synchroteam.com/#attachments) endpoint.pass customer id(you get in the first endpoint) in this endpoint.

if you need more help then comment.

Comment: Thankyou for your response but can you please guide me more on how to use these APIs I mean first I want to test these APIs in Postman i have tried these APIs but im not getting the correct response.